# c# SQL Server : DATETIME datatype

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I am writing a unit test which stores an object with a `DateTime` parameter into a `DATETIME2` SQL Server database column. I then create a temporary `DateTime` object called `new_date_time` and set that value to `DateTime.Now`.

The `new_date_time` value is then used to update the previous value and the SQL query to do this completes successfully.

When re-reading the object back from the database I receive the correct `datetime` values for days/hours/minutes but the `.Ticks` value is different from the `new_date_time` variables `.Ticks` property. The value returned from the read call returns the last 4 digits of the `.Ticks` property as zeros.

Why is this rounding occurring making my `Assert.AreEqual` fail?? :)

Thanks

Comment: Does your unit test cause a query against the database? Your unit test should not depend on the database or change the contents. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30710/how-to-unit-test-an-object-with-database-queries).

Comment: yes I am querying the database, its using a temp variable of type datetime to verify that the update command is updating the correct data in the database

Comment: How is the DateTime2 column defined? Are you using just `datetime2` or `datetime2(n)`?

Comment: datetime2
default precision is allegedly max precision

Comment: Do you use `Getdate` (or `getutcdate`) in your SQL?

Comment: I use neither and pass the whole datetime object as the parameter

Comment: Using `Parameters.AddWithValue`?

Comment: yes using Parameters.AddWithValue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are using `Parameters.AddWithValue` when writing the date to Sql Server. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168(v=vs.110).aspx) the inferred type of a CLR `DateTime` is `SqlDbType.DateTime` and **not** `SqlDbType.DateTime2` so the precision is being lost when writing your date to the database.

Explicitly setting the type to `datetime2` will solve the issue. For example:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@now", DateTime.Now).SqlDbType = 
                                                       SqlDbType.DateTime2;
```

**Edit**

[@marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s) makes a good point with his comment:

> You should read (and embrace!) [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

To avoid these kind of issues from biting you, you could get into the habit of using the `Add` method on the parameters collection which takes the `SqlDbType` in some overloads  and then set the `Value` property on that rather than using the `AddWithValue` method:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@now", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: this looks like the probable culprit... :)

Comment: ok I will try this as originally I was using the same code with the old datetime type which did not work either this seems logical to be the issue.

Comment: You should read (and embrace!) [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @marc_s - I've added an edit to the answer as you make a good point. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your database field is not storing your entire `DateTime.Now` value, because it's not precise enough. Why don't you simply compare your dates after you've formatted them as you like?

eg: (untested):

```
var databaseDate = d1.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff");

var tempDate = d2.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff");

Assert.AreEqual(databaseDate, tempDate);
```

I tested: using `Linq To Entities` My `DateTime.Now` is correctly saved to my `datetime2(7)` and equality test return `True`.

Are you sure you're passing your **correct** datetime value to the database? without truncating it?

Comment: according to:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx

the default precision is the max precision

Comment: what is the required precision to accurately store a .net datetime object?

Comment: yes sure I am passing the correct object as its being modified, its just the .Ticks value is not being reflected as the same value when being compared with the Assert

Comment: Use `HH` not `hh`. `HH` is 24-hour, `hh` is 12-hour.