# Why AddWithValue when is dcd_first_name SQL Server Profile gives me default? and when store procedure execute crash the execution

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have this code:

```
var SQL ="SP_PROC";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, connection)
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dcd_first_name", name);
cmd ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Why does `AddWithValue` when is `dcd_first_name` SQL Server Profile gives me default? And when stored procedure executes, it crashes the execution.

Profile gives me: `EXEC SP_PROC default`

I thought when I pass a null in parameter, in this case name automatically `AddWithValue` convert to `DBNull.Value`. I have to specify it.

Is it the best method to use `AddWithValue` the parameter?

Comment: nope in Profile set default

Comment: Just noticed you didn't do `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`

Comment: I forgot to add here sorry

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AddWithValue` *doesn't* automatically convert from `null` to `DBNull.Value`.

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation on `AddWithValue(string parameterName, Object value)`:

> *value* - 
>   The value to be added. Use DBNull.Value instead of null, to indicate a null value.

Changing the call to the following will fix it:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dcd_first_name", 
                             name == null ? DBNull.Value : (object)name);
```

**Edit**

In the comments you ask if `AddWithValue` is the best way of adding parameters. In my opinion the answer to that is **"no"**.

As per the comment from @marc_s:

> You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results..

For an example of problems that can occur see this SO question - [c# SQL Server : DATETIME datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25515910/c-sharp-sql-server-datetime-datatype/25516421#25516421)

My prefered approach is to use the overload of `Add` that takes the `SqlDbType` and then set the `Value` property afterwards:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dcd_first_name", SqlDbType.VarChar)
              .Value = name == null ? DBNull.Value : (object)name;
```

Comment: It is what I did as you indicate in your answer, but I hadsome curiosity to ask. It was I imagined. Anyway,is it the best method to set parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set the command type to be a stored procedure. After you instantiate the `cmd` object, add this line:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: I forgot to add here sorry

Comment: And it is not the answer I am looking for, I need some why no code correction